# How to update related models with loopback

Tags: has-many, relation, loopback

I have to related models, Question which can have many Answer :

Here's my question.json :

```
{
  "name": "Question",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mysql": {
    "schema": "metal-quizz",
    "table": "Question"
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": true,
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "id",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "label": {
      "type": "String",
      "required": true,
      "length": 255,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "label",
        "dataType": "varchar",
        "dataLength": 255,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "level": {
      "type": "Number",
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "level",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "answers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Answer",
      "foreignKey": "questionId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Here's my answer.json :

```
{
  "name": "Answer",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mysql": {
    "schema": "metal-quizz",
    "table": "Answer"
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": true,
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "id",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "questionId": {
      "type": "Number",
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "questionId",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "label": {
      "type": "String",
      "required": true,
      "length": 255,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "label",
        "dataType": "varchar",
        "dataLength": 255,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "Number",
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 3,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "status",
        "dataType": "tinyint",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 3,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "question": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Question",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

I would like to have a web page with a form which displays a Question and all its related answers and allow me to update them all at the same time.
I managed the display part without any problem but I'm getting nuts about the updating part.

In theory it's possible since I can do it through the explorer via the following routes :

```
PUT /Questions/{id} to update question
PUT /Questions/{id}/answers/{fk} to update answers individually
```

So I created a remote method to do so but I can't get to understand what method of the answers I am allowed to use to update them one by one:

```
Question.putWithDeps = function(question, cb) {
    // Update Question 
    Question.upsert(question, function(err, model) {
        // What code am I supposed to put here to update question.answers ???
    }
};
Question.remoteMethod(
    'putWithDeps',
    {
        http: {path: '/withDeps', verb: 'put'},
        accepts: {arg: 'instance', type: 'object'},
        returns: {root: true, type: 'object' } 
    }
);
```

Am I getting it all wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? Updating many answers with the same value all at once? Or update many answers, all with different values all at once? Why not update them one at a time, like the API gives you out of the box? Have you seen this: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/PersistedModel+REST+API#PersistedModelRESTAPI-Updatematchingmodelinstances ?

Comment: I want to update them one by one since they have different values of course. What I'm wondering about is the proper way to do it :
- do I have to use the Answer model methods
- do I have to use the Question.answers instance model
The link you provided is about routes when I'm trying to do this programatically, I've never thought it could be a good practice to use routes in loopback remote methods... is it ?

Answer (score 3):

It would look something like this (not exact code, just a rough sketch and not tested, exact args might need tweaking). Also would need to modify your remote method to pass in new Answer data:

```
Question.putWithDeps = function(question, answers, cb) {
  // Update Question 
  Question.upsert(question, function(err, question) {

    // get all answers that belong to the parent question
    question.answers({}, function(err, answers) {

      // answers = array of answers that belong to the Question
      // example with index 0:
      answer[0].upsert({answer object}, function(err, answer) {
        // check for err or success
      })

      // or loop on the array and update inside the loop (or promisify using .then())

    });

    // could also destroy all answers and create all new ones
    question.answers.destroyAll(function(err) {

      question.answers.create(<array of new answers>,function(err) {
        ...
      });
    });

  }
};
```

Check out the hasMany docs, the section at the bottom showing the methods added to the model:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasMany+relations